# My CP-SAT program (Google OR Tools) don't execute commands inside the on_solution_callback function

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

Can you please help me? I'm new to python and Google OR-Tools, and I'm not sure how to debug this. Seems like the code is working even before the `def on_solution_callback(self):` line. There's no error but no solutions generated as well. Thank you. Below is my whole code.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

class EmployeesPartialSolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    """Print intermediate solutions."""

    # Here, we retrieve parameter values and assign to respective variables
    def __init__(self, shifts_cashier, shifts_genad, num_cashiers, num_genads, num_days, num_shifts, sols):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self._shifts_cashier = shifts_cashier
        self._shifts_genad = shifts_genad
        self._num_cashiers = num_cashiers
        self._num_genads = num_genads
        self._num_days = num_days
        self._num_shifts = num_shifts
        self._solutions = set(sols)
        self._solution_count = 0

    # Prints solutions in a format
    def on_solution_callback(self):
        print("printttt")
        if self._solution_count in self._solutions:
            print('Solution %i' % self._solution_count)
            for d in range(self._num_days):
                print('Day %i' % d)
                for n in range(self._num_cashiers):
                    is_working = False
                    for s in range(self._num_shifts):
                        if self.Value(self._shifts_cashier[(n, d, s)]):
                            is_working = True
                            print('  Cashier %i works shift %i' % (n, s))
                    if not is_working:
                        print('  Cashier {} does not work'.format(n))
                for g in range(self._num_genads):
                    is_working = False
                    for s in range(self._num_shifts):
                        if self.Value(self._shifts_genad[(g, d, s)]):
                            is_working = True
                            print('  GenAd %i works shift %i' % (g, s))
                    if not is_working:
                        print('  GenAd {} does not work'.format(g))
            print()
        self._solution_count += 1

    def solution_count(self):
        return self._solution_count


def main():
    # Here, we initialize our data variables
    num_cashiers = 4
    num_genads = 4
    num_shifts = 3
    num_days = 3
    all_cashiers = range(num_cashiers)
    all_genads = range(num_genads)
    all_shifts = range(num_shifts)
    all_days = range(num_days)

    # Creates the model
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    # Creates shift variables for cashiers
    # shifts[(n, d, s)]: cashier 'n' works shift 's' on day 'd'
    shifts_cashier = {}
    for n in all_cashiers:
        for d in all_days:
            for s in all_shifts:
                shifts_cashier[(n, d, s)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_n%id%is%i' % (n, d, s))

    # Creates shift variables for general admins
    # shifts[(g, d, s)]: general admin 'g' works shift 's' on day 'd'
    shifts_genad = {}
    for g in all_genads:
        for d in all_days:
            for s in all_shifts:
                shifts_genad[(g, d, s)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_g%id%is%i' % (g, d, s))


    # Each shift is assigned to exactly one cashier and one admin in the schedule period
    for d in all_days:
        for s in all_shifts:
            model.Add(sum(shifts_cashier[(n, d, s)] for n in all_cashiers) == 1)
            model.Add(sum(shifts_genad[(g, d, s)] for n in all_genads) == 1)

    # Each cashier works at most one shift per day
    for n in all_cashiers:
        for d in all_days:
            model.Add(sum(shifts_cashier[(n, d, s)] for s in all_shifts) <= 1)

    # Each general admin works at most one shift per day
    for g in all_genads:
        for d in all_days:
            model.Add(sum(shifts_genad[(g, d, s)] for s in all_shifts) <= 1)

    # min_shifts_per_cashier is the largest integer such that every cashier
    # can be assigned at least that many shifts. If the number of cashiers doesn't
    # divide the total number of shifts over the schedule period,
    # some cashiers have to work one more shift, for a total of
    # min_shifts_per_cashier + 1.
    min_shifts_per_cashier = (num_shifts * num_days) // num_cashiers
    max_shifts_per_cashier = min_shifts_per_cashier + 1
    for n in all_cashiers:
        num_shifts_worked_c = sum(shifts_cashier[(n, d, s)] for d in all_days for s in all_shifts)
        model.Add(min_shifts_per_cashier <= num_shifts_worked_c)
        model.Add(num_shifts_worked_c <= max_shifts_per_cashier)

    # min_shifts_per_genad is the largest integer such that every genad
    # can be assigned at least that many shifts. If the number of genads doesn't
    # divide the total number of shifts over the schedule period,
    # some genads have to work one more shift, for a total of
    # min_shifts_per_genad + 1.
    min_shifts_per_genad = (num_shifts * num_days) // num_genads
    max_shifts_per_genad = min_shifts_per_genad + 1
    for n in all_genads:
        num_shifts_worked_g = sum(shifts_genad[(g, d, s)] for d in all_days for s in all_shifts)
        model.Add(min_shifts_per_genad <= num_shifts_worked_g)
        model.Add(num_shifts_worked_g <= max_shifts_per_genad)

    # Creates the solver and solve
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.linearization_level = 0

    # Display the first five solutions.
    a_few_solutions = range(2)
    solution_printer = EmployeesPartialSolutionPrinter(shifts_cashier, shifts_genad, num_cashiers, num_genads, num_days, num_shifts, a_few_solutions)
    solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)

    # Statistics.
    print()
    print('Statistics')
    print('  - conflicts       : %i' % solver.NumConflicts())
    print('  - branches        : %i' % solver.NumBranches())
    print('  - wall time       : %f s' % solver.WallTime())
    print('  - solutions found : %i' % solution_printer.solution_count())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: your problem has no solution. So it is not unusual for the solution callback not printing anything.

Comment: Hi Laurent. I see you're from Google. Do you have any idea on how I can handle this and get my expected output? Thank you

Comment: Check your model. It is wrong.

Comment: @mrd_ds a quick check in PyCharm suggests that this line is wrong `model.Add(sum(shifts_genad[(g, d, s)] for n in all_genads) == 1)` (notice the g and the n)

Comment: Stradivari, thank you so much. This is such a big help! Can you advise how were you able to quickly check it? THANKS A LOT!

Comment: PyCharm is a pretty good IDE, so it shows me a warning `Local variable 'g' might be referenced before assignment` in the editor